# How to make nested lists with numbers and alphabetical

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a nested list to change from numbers to alphabetical. You can see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nettlepatch/xLoq3zm5/) where I have the class `alpha` I would like the `3.1.1` to change to `a.` Any ideas?

```css
strong {
   font-weight: 700;
  }

.maincontent ol {
  margin: 25px;
}

ol.tc li ol.d {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha !important;
  color: red;}

ol.tc {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol.tc li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ol.tc li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")".";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; /* space between number and text */
}

ol.tc {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol.tc li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")".";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; /* space between number and text */
}

ol.alpha {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

ol.alpha li:before {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; /* space between number and text */
    color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ol class="tc">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Preconditions</strong><br>
        <ol class="tc">
            <li>Before we can provide you with Pay Monthly Services, you will need to:</li>         
            <li>Complete our application process and provide us with any information which we reasonably ask for.</li>
            <li>Have a credit score and provide us with inancial security which is satisfactory to us. </li>
            <li>Provide us with valid proof of identity and evidence that you are permanently living in the Republic of Ireland.
             <li>Provide us with valid proof that you are aged over 18 years. </li>
        </ol>
      </li>

    <li><strong>Tariff Limits</strong><br>
      <ol class="tc">
           <li>Tariffs may include a limit on the volume of Services, including minutes, texts and/or internet access, which can be used without extra charge. Charges for all Services in excess of any Tariff limits will be charged at the rates set out in the charges.</li>
      </ol>
    </li>




    <li><strong>Call Charges covered by Tariff limits</strong><br>
      <ol class="tc">
          <li>Tariff limits cover calls made in Ireland to:
      <ol>
      
      <ol class="alpha">      
        <li>standard Irish landlines; and</li>
        <li>08 numbers allocated to Irish mobile network operators.</li>  
      </ol>
    </li> 



  </ul>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

html markup not valid

```
<ol class="tc">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

see answer below

```css
strong {
   font-weight: 700;
  }

.maincontent ol {
  margin: 25px;
}

ol.tc li ol.d {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha !important;
  color: red;}

ol.tc {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol.tc li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ol.tc li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")".";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; /* space between number and text */
}

ol.tc {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol.tc li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")".";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; /* space between number and text */
}

ol.alpha {
    counter-reset: item;    
}

ol.alpha li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha) ". ";
     counter-increment: item;    
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px; 
    color: pink;
    
}
```

```html
<ol class="tc">
    <li><strong>Preconditions</strong>
        <br/>
        <ol class="tc">
            <li>Before we can provide you with Pay Monthly Services, you will need to:</li>
            <li>Complete our application process and provide us with any information which we reasonably ask for.</li>
            <li>Have a credit score and provide us with inancial security which is satisfactory to us.</li>
            <li>Provide us with valid proof of identity and evidence that you are permanently living in the Republic of Ireland.</li>
            <li>Provide us with valid proof that you are aged over 18 years.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Tariff Limits</strong>
        <br/>
        <ol class="tc">
            <li>Tariffs may include a limit on the volume of Services, including minutes, texts and/or internet access, which can be used without extra charge. Charges for all Services in excess of any Tariff limits will be charged at the rates set out in the charges.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Call Charges covered by Tariff limits</strong>
        <br/>
        <ol class="tc">
            <li>Tariff limits cover calls made in Ireland to:
                <ol class="alpha">
                    <li>standard Irish landlines; and</li>
                    <li>08 numbers allocated to Irish mobile network operators.</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but it is probably because your post is nothing but a huge blob of code. No word of explanation, not pointing out what is different, why it works, nothing. This solves the specific problem of the OP as long as they're willing to copy/paste your code and hope for the best. That isn't, generally, useful.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML you have is not valid, the only permitted content for `<ol>` and `<ul>` is zero or `<li>` elements.

For the alphabetical style, you will need the correct pseudo `content` for it.

```
.alpha li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)".";
}
```

See the update demo please - http://jsfiddle.net/sjqvpuuL/

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")".";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px;
}
.alpha li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)".";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <strong>Preconditions</strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Before we can provide you with Pay Monthly Services, you will need to:</li>
            <li>Complete our application process and provide us with any information which we reasonably ask for.</li>
            <li>Have a credit score and provide us with inancial security which is satisfactory to us.</li>
            <li>Provide us with valid proof of identity and evidence that you are permanently living in the Republic of Ireland.</li>
            <li>Provide us with valid proof that you are aged over 18 years.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Tariff Limits</strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Tariffs may include a limit on the volume of Services, including minutes, texts and/or internet access, which can be used without extra charge. Charges for all Services in excess of any Tariff limits will be charged at the rates set out in the charges.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Call Charges covered by Tariff limits</strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Tariff limits cover calls made in Ireland to:
                <ol class="alpha">
                    <li>standard Irish landlines; and</li>
                    <li>08 numbers allocated to Irish mobile network operators.</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would be an example for what you are trying to achieve:

```
<ol type="1">
<li> Decide on a subject.
   <ol type="a">
   <li> Business
   <li> Family
   <li> Hobby
   </ol>
<li> Acquire the necessary tools and materials.
   <ol type="a">
   <li> Web browser
   <li> Text editor or HTML editor
   <li> Graphics and clip-art
   <li> Graphics editor
   </ol>
<li> Write the HTML source code.
</ol>
```

Just try it inside JFiddle without CSS code and change it to your wish.

[image: JFiddle example]

Comment: @ Ybrin Thanks. What I would like though is to have a list like (1, 1.1, 1.2. ) then (2, 2.1, a, b), (3, 3.1, 3.2)... that sort of thing. From what I can see I would need to add a counter reset which seem to work fine but for when I want to change the lists to something different like alphabetical.